# Error con replace java en entorno WebSphere

Tags: java

Necesito ejecutar estos simples replace a un monto que recibo de un formulario. Pero el proyecto en el que debo hacerlo se encuentra con WebSphere y no se por que me lanza un error

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String monto = "1.000,02";
    System.out.println("Monto formulario: " + monto);
    monto = monto.replace(".", "");
    // monton = monton.replace('.','');
    System.out.println("replace  1: " + monto);
    monto = monto.replace(",", ".");
    System.out.println("replace  2: " + monto);
}
```

Ejecuto esto perfectamente tanto en Eclipse como en NetBeans y no hay problema pero en WebSphere me salta este error
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y si lo intento con comilla simple tampoco funciona pues me dice

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: ¿Cuál es tu versión de Java? ¿De este modo funciona: **`monto.replace(".", Character.MIN_VALUE);`**?

Comment: tengo esta java version 1.8.0_111

Answer (score 0):

Se debe a que al hacer un `.replace` en String puedes dar nada como valor porque se indica como `.replace(target, replacement)`. Pero si indicas comillas simples se vuelve un `.replace(oldChar, newChar)` y no puedes darle nada.

Esto se debe a como se representa char y String. Si ponemos:

```
char prueba ='';
String pruebo ="";
```

En la primera línea nos dará error de Empty character literal, pero String es diferente. Al final char es un tipo primitivo.

Puedes "intentar" y pongo entrecomillas porque a mi no me convence. Ponerlo en Unicode, Min_Value o pasale un null.

Unicode

```
char c = '\u0000';
```

Min_Value

```
char c = Character.MIN_VALUE;
```

Null char

```
char c = '\0';
```